# Two javascript slideshows with if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, layer

I'm trying to make a second slideshow on a floating layer. However, the main slideshow stopped working. I can't make both work at the same time.

This is the original code for the main slideshow:

```
var imgs = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];


document.onkeydown = function(event) {
 var e = event || window.event;
 if (e.keyCode == '37') { // left
 changeImage(-1);![1]
 } else if (e.keyCode == '39') { // right
 changeImage(1);
 }
}

function changeImage(dir) {
var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + dir] || imgs[(dir==1) ? 0 : imgs.length-1];
var index = imgs.indexOf(img.src);
};
```

I have tried an if condition for the second slideshow to work only when the floating layer in which it is contained is active, but I can't get it right.
Like this:

```
 if ($("#floatingLayer").is(":visible") == true) { ORIGINAL SLIDESHOW CODE ABOVE };
```

If it helps, this is the code to toggle the floating layer:

```
 function ToggleFloatingLayer(DivID){
  $('#' + DivID).fadeToggle(0);
 };
```

Can anyone help me? What should I change? I want the original layer to be working by default but to stop when I toggle the floating layer on. Then only the second slideshow should work.
Thank you

Comment: If you can show us a demo (eg: jsfiddle) , then the question will be more clear..

Comment: you could just use a variable to keep track if the original slide show should be active, just wrap it in an if block that would only work if the variable you created is true and when the floating div is shown make the variable false

Comment: I'm so confused... How can I do that?